# Error:(67, 51) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, diamond-operator

I want to use [this](https://github.com/guoguibing/librec) library, I cloned it and imported it into IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3, with JDK 1.8.0_77, but when I want to run the main method I get this error:

```
Error:(422, 50) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

what is going on here? how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a collection with the new (in Java 7) diamond operator,

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- the diamond operator.
```

In earlier versions of Java, you must specify the generic on the right hand side like

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // <-- No diamond operator.
```

**or** you could modify your IDE preferences to target Java 7+.